# import excel multiple values to ms access combo box

Tags: import, combobox, ms-access-2016, multiple-value

I want to import excel table data to ms access table.
but an error occurs(violated key rules, the record field data erased) when i import excel multiple values such as ["a","b","c"] to ms access combo box(table/query) and it returns blank

i tried import excel data to ms access short text column and change the column to combo box(table/query). but it recognize it as single values such as ["a,b,c"] (refer pic)

anyone knows how to import excel multiple values to ms access combo box(table/query)
i don't want the ["MO,QA"] want to bring data clean/nice and keep table relation with other table(combo box table/query)

[image]